# Maintain all xml elements in xml file

Tags: xslt

in my xml file elements are not constant like say my file is

```
<alpha>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
  <c>...</c>
</alpha>
<alpha>
  <a>...</a>
  <c>...</c>
</alpha>
<alpha>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
</alpha>
<alpha>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
  <c>...</c>
</alpha>
```

I meant to say i want to maintain all elements in my xml file by creating the non existing element in the set and should skip if any of the element is existed using xslt. Pls. help me to solve this problem.

Want OutPut Like as below for non existing elements with value 0 by creating in xslt.

**

```
<alpha>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>...</b>
      <c>...</c>
    </alpha>
    <alpha>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>0</b>
      <c>...</c>
    </alpha>
    <alpha>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>...</b>
      <c>0</c>
    </alpha>
    <alpha>
      <a>...</a>
      <b>...</b>
      <c>...</c>
    </alpha>
```

**

Comment: you need to highlight your XML and then use the "code" button (010 101) on the editor toolbar to get useful results!

Comment: and what do you want to do with this XML and XSLT? Convert it to an XML that has all the elements for all the <alpha> nodes?

Comment: I don't understand what you need, can you provide a small example (i.e with less then 5 tags) of the input and the output you expect/want

Comment: @marc_c, I quite enjoyed watching that code evolve as you edited it, and I refreshed the screen. It was like *animation*.

Comment: I want to create the non existing xml elements where they not exists with value zero.

Comment: @naidu: yeah I have understood but not really sure how `easy` is it feasible in `xslt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
    <xsl:template match="a|b|c">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="alpha">
        <xsl:variable name="alpha" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="forced">
            <forced>
                <a>0</a>
                <b>0</b>
                <c>0</c>
            </forced>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="$forced/forced/*">
                <xsl:variable name="current" select="name()"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="exists($alpha/*[name() = $current])">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$alpha/*[name() = $current]"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$forced/forced/*[name() = $current]"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="alpha">
                <alpha>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="a">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="a"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <a>0</a>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="b">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <b>0</b>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="c">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="c"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <c>0</c>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                </alpha>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It won't work with XSLT 1.0; your variable $forced is a RTF (Result Tree Fragment), and you can't use RTF within a XPath expression.

Comment: Very well, i added a 1.0 template as well. Not that i'm very fond of it. I always use saxon for processing and 2.0 is so much better.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, slightly modified identity transformation can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      <xsl:if test="self::alpha">
        <xsl:if test="not(a)"><a>0</a></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(b)"><b>0</b></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(c)"><c>0</c></xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Be aware that the above does not create the a, b, c elements in this particular order (since I don't think this is really necessary). It merely makes sure that all three of them are there, and copies the rest of the input as it is.